# write a list from values for the same key MapReduce Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Does anyone know how can i write to the output file the list of values for the same key in one line?
for example, I have this: (key, values)
0 [0,2,4,5] ,
1 [1,2,3]
and i want to the output:

`0 0 2 4 5 
1 1 2 3`

instead of

`0 0 
0 2 
0 4`

... etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate all the values in your reducer to a string and write the value out as `Text`. For example

```
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) ... {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (IntWritable value : values) {
        sb.append(String.valueOf(value.get()) + " ");
    }

    context.write(key, new Text(sb.toString()));

}
```

Comment: Right, very good and simple solution!!! Thank you! I'm wondering if there is another way!

Comment: Is there something specific you're looking for, or hoping to achieve?

Comment: No! Your answer gives me exactly the output which i want. It is very simple and i was wondering if there is another way. Just for information, nothing else!!!

Comment: If you're looking for some standard API method - not that _I_ know. When you write to the context, it's per line, so the only way I could think of was _this_ :-)